# incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AAViewController *__strong' from 'UIView *const_strong'

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

Checking a controller in navigation controller stack, but assigning a controller value get a warning
 'incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AAViewController *__strong' from 'UIView *const_strong''

AAViewController *controller;

```
for(UIView *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{            
     if([view isKindOfClass:[AAViewController class]])
     {
         controller = view;
         break;
     }
}
```

i got a error in controller = view 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type cast it.

```
controller=(AAViewController *)view;
```

Comment: Correct, but you should also point out to the OP that the example code  is using the wrong type and very bad naming for the local loop variable; a view controller is not a view.

Comment: @sabeer : I hope you have read jlehr's comment... Please always follow these.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
AAViewController *controller;

for(UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{

    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[AAViewController class]])
    {
        controller = viewController;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want another type of viewController in the collection then change the if statement according to your required viewController class

Comment: already tried but getting warning thank you for your responce